# How I create a smart splitting regex on special characters?

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I am struggling to create a special regex, that tokenize in smartly the text. Some of the rules are:

- Don't split on "," or "." if they appear between two digits. ex: "12,3" or "12.3"
- Split for all other special characters besides " ' "

Here is a an example of an input and what I am looking for:

Input: "J'aime coder avec python 3.7, et 3,8. c'est dûr de coder avec 3.9!"

Wanted output: `["J'aime coder avec python 3.7" , ",", "et 3,8", ".", "c'est dûr de coder avec 3.9", "!"]`

I have tried something like that:

```
reg = re.compile(r"[^\d+\,\d+]+[^\d+\.\d+]+[^A-Za-z' ôöàçèéêëïâîÀÁÂÄÅÃÆÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝYüÜÚúÙùÛû]")
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Coming close to your desired result with e.g. [`[\w']+(?:[\s.,]\w+)*|\W+`](https://regex101.com/r/ogmmiT/1)

Comment: Try with this regex: `re.split(r"((?!>\d)[,.](?!\d))|([!+$#])", text)`

Answer (score 1):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HlC4gO/1)):

```py
import re

s = """\
J'aime coder avec python 3.7, et 3,8. c'est dûr de coder avec 3.9!
This is other phrase.And this is another."""

pat = re.compile(
    r"(?:(.*?)\s*([.,!?])\s*(?=\D|\Z))|(?:(.*?\D)\s*([.,!?])\s*(?=\d|\Z))"
)

out = [v for v in pat.split(s) if v]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
["J'aime coder avec python 3.7", ',', 'et 3,8', '.', "c'est dûr de coder avec 3.9", '!', 'This is other phrase', '.', 'And this is another', '.']
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It works pretty good, but don't realise the second condition, which is splitting on all other special characters but " ' ".
For example if I use this input:
"J'aime coder avec python 3.7, et 3,8. c'est dûr de cod/er <br> avec 3.9!" 
It won't split on "/", "<" and ">"

Comment: @yassine I suggest first to parse the HTML string with HTML parser (for example with `beautifulsoup` not regex) and then afterwards parse the string with regex.

Comment: Actually, for different political reasons I have to treat this brute data with only regex. and let's say it's not a big deal for html part. It still didn't split on the "/" for example. I have infinte of special characters (data coming from everywhere) and the regex should just understand that it needs to split on it.